# Listen to events without knowing sender in C#?

Tags: c#, events

I'm currently diving into the more advanced C# topics and have a questions about events:

If I understood that right, I need to know the object (instance) that raises an event in order to listen to it:

```
class IWantToListen {
    public IWantToListen(IAmSending s) {
        s.OnTrigger += HandleTrigger;
    }

    public void HandleTrigger(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // react to event
    }
}

public class IAmSending {
    public event EventHandler OnTrigger;

    public void TriggerEvent(EventArgs e) {
        OnTrigger(this, e);
    }
}
```

In order to have my `IWantToListen` instance listen to events from my `IAmSending` instance, I have to pass at some point the reference to that specific instance.

But what if I want my `IWantToListen` instances to listen to events from all instances of `IAmSending` and those instances are dynamically created. I would have to manually let `IWantToListen` know that there is a new `IAmSending` instance that it has to subscribe to. Is there no other possibility? I think I'm looking for something that would work like this:

```
public class IWantToListen {
    public IWantToListen() {
        EventDistributionSystem.AddListener("OnTrigger", HandleTrigger);
    }

    public void HandleTrigger(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // react to event
    }
}

public class IAmSending {
    public void TriggerEvent(EventArgs e) {
        EventDistributionSystem.Send("OnTrigger", this, e);
    }
}
```

Of course that's only a rough sketch with room for improvement, but I think you get the idea. Anyway, I couldn't for the life mine find anything doing this or even somebody asking for it. I could probably build a singleton `EventDistributionSystem` class on my own, but the fact that it doesn't prominently exist already raises the question if there is a reason for that. Is this considered bad design? If yes, why?

Comment: Create an additional static event in IAmSending. Each instance of IAmSending would then not only raise the instance event, but also the static event. You could then also eliminate the instance event if desired, as the static event would fullfil the same functionality.  (1/3)

Comment: (2/3) However. be very cautious and diligent with static events. As a static event "never" disappears (as it is not member of an instance object that could be garbage collected), it will "forever" hold any subscribed event handler unless such a handler is explicitely unsubscribed again. As an event handler delegate also holds a reference to the target object, a static event will keep the target object of an subscribed event handler alive. Forgetting to unsubscribe event handlers from static events will keep the target object(s) alive "forever" and can thus lead to memory/resource leaks...

Comment: (3/3) However, if you use case is limited to only IWantToListen observing IAmSending, you could eschew the suggestion about a static event and use observer pattern (using static members) or some other form of callback mechanism between IAmSending and IWantToListen. But, if you cannot alter the code of IAmSending, you unfortunately will be forced to find a way to manually subscribe to each IAmSending instance (which requires your code to be able to somehow be aware/notified of creations of IAmSending instances)

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of making the event static. That should work pretty well. The problem with unsubscribing also would exist in the mockup EventDistributionSystem, I think. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: There are ways to avoid resource leaks when forgetting to unsubscribe from static events using WeakReferences. However, this would require custom event accessors or custom "weak event handler" types which would split the target object from the provided event handler delegates (to stuff them in a WeakReference), and realizing invocation of the target method through "open delegates" (https://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html), but this plus keeping track of all that to enable clean event unsubscribing will become quite involved...

Comment: Two pointers with regard to my last comment: http://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/08/event_subscription_using_weak_references/ and http://paulstovell.com/blog/weakevents